# Merging two android library and generate one aar

Tags: android, gradle, merge, android-library, aar

Is it possible to Merge two android library and generate one aar file

I have

```
> :app (application)
> :library-1 (library)
> :library-2 (library)
```

:library-2 is dependent on :library-1 and :app dependents on :library-2

both libraries as res and package is different

I need a single aar from :library-2, :library-1. Is this possible ?

Comment: even if it were possible, what is wrong with the current configuration?

Comment: we have situation like sharing the merged :library-1 and :library-2 AAR to be used as dependency in a 3rd party client app

Comment: No you cannot. That's not how dependency management works in Java. Look into maven to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You need you extract java and res file from both library projects and import that file onto one project.

Comment: we are maintaining it has separate modules handled by different teams. package names are different. So we do not want to convert them as one modules